# reload a module and dependent top level module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

In python, is there a mechanism to:

1. reload top-level module (`sys.modules['__main__']`) or
2. just update a function in top-level module during runtime?

Say we have top level `dsu.py` and we want to patch imported module `updating.simple` during runtime by adding a function to it, then patch `main()` in `dsu.py` by adding a call to the function added to `updating.simple`. Finally, we want to reload `updating.simple` to take patched code into use and then reload `dsu.py` to call new function in `updating.simple` with reload-mechanism in signal handler.

`dsu.py:`

```
import importlib, signal, time, sys
import updating.simple

def update_handler(sig, frame):
    importlib.reload(updating.simple)
    # 1. reload "this" module here or 2. reload only main()

def main():
    while True:
        print("Result : %i" % updating.simple.computation(1,2))
        # patch with: print("Another: %i" % updating.simple.anothercomputation(2,1)) go here
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, update_handler)
    main()
```

`updating\simple.py:`

```
def computation(a,b):
    return a * b
```

While question is related to dynamic updating (or monkey-patching), I've added the code with patches and test (`python3 test.py`) for reference:

https://bitbucket.org/vilvo/py-reload-module-and-dependent/src

Expected behavior:

```
$ python3 test.py 
Starting the process: python3.4 ./dsu.py
Result : 2
Updating module with a patch that adds a method
and the added method is called from the main()
patching file updating/simple.py
diff --git a/updating/simple.py b/updating/simple.py
index 6bd6318..6434e5a 100644
--- a/updating/simple.py
+++ b/updating/simple.py
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 def computation(a,b):
     return a * b
+
+def anothercomputation(a,b):
+    return a * b * b * a
patching file ./dsu.py
diff --git a/dsu.py b/dsu.py
index 508f7c6..74d27e3 100644
--- a/dsu.py
+++ b/dsu.py
@@ -8,6 +8,7 @@ def update_handler(sig, frame):

 def main():
     while True:
+        print("Another: %i" % updating.simple.anothercomputation(2,1))
         print("Result : %i" % updating.simple.computation(1,2))
         time.sleep(0.5)

diff --git a/updating/simple.py b/updating/simple.py
index 6bd6318..6434e5a 100644
--- a/updating/simple.py
+++ b/updating/simple.py
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 def computation(a,b):
     return a * b
+
+def anothercomputation(a,b):
+    return a * b * b * a
Trigger dynamic software update with user signal
Another: 4
Result : 2
Reverting patches
Another: 4
Result : 2
Trigger dynamic software update with user signal
Result : 2
Stopping the process with pid 11547
Cleaning files generated by Python
Removing __pycache__/
Removing updating/__pycache__/
```

My two trials are available in git-repository:

```
$ git log --oneline
7c7c828 Trial on reloading only updated main() and executing it
2fd68d6 Study on dynamic update of a module and dependent with Python
```

Any insight appreciated, I'm also curious if this is possible with frame hack.